# Forcing links that display modal content to always open in the current tab

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a link that opens a modal window containing some text.
I want to prevent users from opening this link in a new browser tab.

Is there a way of saying that this link should always open in the current browser tab, even if the user explicitly asks for it to be opened in a new tab (i.e. ctrl+click).

I have tried `target='_self'` to no avail.

Comment: AFAIK you can't override the user opening it in a new tab. (In the end, there's nothing to stop them copy-pasting the URL.)

Comment: Although you could make it a button instead.

Comment: yes as @gcampbell suggested if the link only opens the Modal make it a button.

Comment: @gcampbell I like that idea, I'll post my solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gcampbell suggested using a button, and then I remembered that the framework I'm using (rails) has a `button_to` helper method which generates the following:

```
= button_to "Say hello", contact_path, method: 'get', class: 'button', remote: true

<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/contact-me" data-remote="true">
  <input class="button" value="Say hello" type="submit">
</form>
```

That'll do. Thanks @gcampbell, I had absolutely no idea html buttons (and inputs) had this behaviour.